# Double ckecked locking for network calls

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

In my application I have the following code:

```
Folders[] folders = getFolders();
Folder folder = resolveFolder(folders,pattern);
if(folder == null){
    if(createFolderOn()){
        synchronized(lock){
            folders = getFolders(); //here I Am refreshing the folders array. This is needed because some other thread might have already created the folder.
            folder = resolveFolder(folders,pattern);
            if(folder == null){
                createFolder();
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

`getFolders()` and `createFolder()` are indeed network calls. Is it right to perform such kind of Double Checked Locking when every thread loads its data  via network operation? The idea is not to create the same folder corresponding to the pattern more than once. The provider guarantees that the folder is returned as soon as it is created so `getFolders()` and `createFolder()` are synchronous calls.

**Edit**
Forgot to mention that I have no control over the folder provider. It does not restrict folder creation (folders with the same name can be created multiple times). Since my requirements prohibit folder duplication I introduced the above approach

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into simplifying your approach. Like in: just make `createFolder()` safe to be called repeatedly.

In other words: that module that **really** does a file system operation in order to create a folder - that module should check if the folder already exists. If so, `createFolder()` simply does nothing. If the folder isn't there - then that module can use its own internal locking to make sure it creates the folder only once. Don't put this *internal* detail onto clients using your "network" services.

Given the comment by the OP about not owning the "network" service: then do *not* consume these "services". Instead create your own **wrapping** service that provides means to check respectively create folders in a safe way.

Your code is violating the single responsibility rule: the client code does two things - its actual "business logic" - but then it *also* worries about locking this "directory service". Instead: create your own directory service that takes care about locking.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have no control over the folder provider. It does not restrict folder creation (folders with the same name can be created multiple times). Since my requirements prohibit folder duplication I introduced the above approach. Anyway, I agree that if achievable it should have done this way.

Comment: You probably want to enhance your question with such information.

Comment: @DeyanG. If a folder is identified by name, how can you create multiple folders with the same name?  If there can be more than one "folderA", how can you know which one you get when you access "folderA"?  Something doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @DeyanG. And then I enhanced my answer. Hopefully you find it helpful.

Comment: @AndrewHenle this is the idea - to prevent creation of multiple folders with the same name. As I said there is no such restriction at the provider side. In `resolveFolder()`  method an exception is thrown when more than one folder with the same name exists.

Comment: @GhostCat actually my idea was that the code in question restrains the client to create more than one folder. If folder does not exist it just creates it, otherwise returns the resolved folder,  i.e.  plays the role of locking directory service